# Building multiples files in VSCode and WSL and C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have tested to code multiple files on vscode with WSL by doing

```
code .
```

in the good folder.

I have three files.

And here is the error message I obtain, whereas the code is correct :

> g++: error: helloworld.cpp: No such file or directory
>
> g++: error: file2.cpp: No such file or directory
>   g++: error: file3.cpp: No such file or directory
>
> g++: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

And here is my tasks.json file :

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "helloworld.cpp","file2.cpp","file3.cpp",
                "-o",
                "executable.out"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please, could you help to solve that issue whereas with a single file as mentioned here, that perfectly works :

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl#_modifying-tasksjson

I also precise that the .cpp files are not in the .vscode folder, but in the main folder of the project.
[image]
Thanks in advance

ps : I saw several threads about that issue, but that did not solve my issue.

Comment: If you run in terminal your build command in desired directory, what is the output?

Comment: I  tested in terminal manually, to do g++ -g helloworld.cpp file2.cpp -o fileexec ,    and it compiles. but my issue is different, as you can see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original example with `tasks.json` has arguments:

```
            "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
```

which is fine, because `${file}` will contain the absolute path to the actual file so it doesn't matter where is `cwd` set. If you have:

```
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "helloworld.cpp","file2.cpp","file3.cpp",
                "-o",
                "executable.out"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
```

the VSCode is looking for files `/usr/bin/helloworld.cpp`, `/usr/bin/file2.cpp`, `/usr/bin/file3.cpp` - which is clearly wrong.

The solution would be to change the current directory to the current workspace folder:

```
"options": {
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
},
```

For all possible variables consult the [reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)

Comment: They did not explain that here : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl    thank you for the reference. it could help me